# Appropriate type of regression for evolution of relative tumor size over time in two groups?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, robust

I am looking into data from a cohort study with two groups of patients with melanomas. Group A is beeing treated while group B is not. The relative size of several melanomas (relative to the initial size) in each patient is recoreded over time at varying intervals (varying within and between individuals).

I have thought of using a robust (because some melanomas show an atypical evolution and suddenly start growing rappidly while others simply disappear) linear mixed model (specified as `Relative.Tumor.Volume ~ Time*Treatment+(1|Individual/MelanomaID)`) to investigate if the evolution of the relative melanoma size is affect by treatment, however I am concerned by the fact that, as relative size is considered, the size at `Time = 0` will be 1 for every melanoma and patient (and therefore I will have zero variance initially and a variance increasing over time).

Because the trend of each group is different, using the size relative to the mean tumor size of the experimental period is not an option, since then the initial size would be higher in one group than in the other one.

Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why use relative size? Just model the size as is. You already have a variable for time anyway.

Comment: @FransRodenburg I used the relative size to be able to graphically compare the melanomas which are of very variable sizes. Of course this is not necessary for the model but then I found out that the model only converges when I use the relative volume instead of the volume...

Comment: Have you tried transforming the volume? Like $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$, or just $\log(x)$

Comment: Transformations work, thank you very much :)

Comment: How were the two cohorts selected? If no randomization was used to assign patients to cohorts, you may have to consider adjusting for a propensity score to make sure you are comparing like with like.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement there are quite a number of sources of bias between both cohorts in fact. To my defense, I was just given the data and asked to analyze it and was not involved in study design :/ I made a list of all problems I found in this study and they will all be discussed in the paper. I am confident that my co-authors will agree. But actually the objective of the analysis is only to identify if there is a trend justifying further investigation, not to produce evidence of the highest quality.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement while you are absolutely right to point this out, my question was mainly about the types of models suitable for this kind of data and not about other factors of the study design. But thank you for conforting me in my views on the limitations of the study

Comment: Any difference you will find between A and B will be confounded by inherent differences between patients in the two cohorts. For example, patients in Group A may be older (on average) than those in Group B so the difference you discover in your analysis cannot be attributed to treatment alone, since it will be muddled by the age difference.  The study design is very important in this case because it will determine whether the results of the statistical analysis are actually interpretable.